# How to calculate a rotating week schedule with actual dates and times within a date range in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose there is database table structure as follows. Aim of the application is to have a scheduling tool based based on rotating weeks.
For example, a customer will have scheduled appointments from 1 Jan 2021 till 31 Dec 2021, with the first week an appoint every Monday 8am - 10am and friday 9am-11am, and every second week every Tuesday 1pm - 4pm.

```
Period                        WeekRotations             Appointments
------                        -------------             --------------
ID          (PK, int)<--\    ID         (PK, int)<--\   ID             (PK, int)
DateStart   (date)       \-->PeriodID   (FK, int)    \->WeekRotationID (FK, int)
DateEnd     (date)           SequenceNr (int)           DayOfWeek      (int)
CustomerID  (FK, int)                                   TimeStart      (datetime)
                                                        TimeEnd        (datetime)
```

So the 'Period' table holds the relation to the customer, and defines the period the appointment should be scheduled. It can be an infinite list for any customer, but never overlaps for a customer. For the above example this would be:

```
ID      DateStart      DateEnd      CustomerID
10      2020-01-01     2020-12-31   99
```

Data for the WeekRotations for the above example would be the following. There can be an unlimited amount of weekrotations.

```
ID      PeriodID       SequenceNr
100     10             1
101     10             2
```

Data for the Appointments for the above example would be:

```
ID      WeekRotationID DayOfWeek      TimeStart           TimeEnd
500     100            0 (=monday)    1900-01-01 08:00    1900-01-01 10:00
501     100            5 (=friday)    1900-01-01 09:00    1900-01-01 11:00
502     101            1 (=tuesday)   1900-01-01 13:00    1900-01-01 16:00
```

The only solution we have for the moment is to get the appointments for a given day by doing a SELECT with an inner join on all and:

```
      WHERE SequenceNr= ABS(NrOfWeeksFromStartdate % NrOfWeekRotations) + 1
```

and where NrOfWeeksFromStartDate is calculated as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, FLOOR(DATEDIFF( d, [dbo].[GetPrevMonday](CONVERT(DATETIME, '2020-01-01', 102)), [dbo].[GetPrevMonday](DateStart)) / CONVERT( float, 7))) AS NrOfWeeksFromStartdate
```

However this results in a fairly complex sql query, and morever this is not efficient, as we have to loop over the entire year and query every day one by one!

Is there any way to get the list of actual dates and times of the actual appointments in a single query?

---------- EDIT ----------------------------------

This is a simplified sql statement example of what we are using currently.
So if we need the appointments for a whole year, we have to execute this statement 365 times. This offcourse isn't efficient, and we want to do this in one single query.

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT 
    CONVERT(int, FLOOR(DATEDIFF( d, [dbo].[GetPrevMonday](CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-01-01', 102)), [dbo].[GetPrevMonday](DateStart)) / CONVERT( float, 7))) AS NrOfWeeksFromStartdate,  
    (SELECT COUNT(WeekRotations.ID) FROM WeekRotations WHERE PeriodID=Periods.ID) AS NrOfWeekRotations,
    *
FROM 
    Customers INNER JOIN Periods ON Customers.ID=Periods.CustomerID 
    INNER JOIN WeekRotations ON Periods.ID=WeekRotations.PeriodID 
    INNER JOIN Appointments ON Appointments.WeekRotationID = WeekRotations.ID  
WHERE
    CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-01-01', 102) BETWEEN DateStart AND DateEnd 
    AND DayOfWeek=4          
) TBL

WHERE SequenceNr = ABS(NrOfWeeksFromStartdate % NrOfWeekRotations) + 1
```

---------- EDIT 2 ----------------------------------
GetPrevMonday function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPrevMonday]
(
  @INPUTDATE DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @DOW INT
      SET @INPUTDATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @INPUTDATE, 111)
      SET @DOW = DATEPART(DW, @INPUTDATE)
      SET @DOW = (@DOW + @@DATEFIRST - 1) %7
      IF @DOW = 0 SET @DOW = 7

      RETURN DATEADD(DD, 1 - @DOW,@INPUTDATE)

    END
GO
```

---------- EDIT 3 ----------------------------------
---------- EXAMPLES --------------------------------

```
One appointment each monday for Q1 2021:

Periods

ID    DateStart   DateEnd    CustomerID
1     2021-1-1    2021-3-31  1

WeekRotations

ID    PeriodID    SequenceNr
100   1           1

Appointments

ID      WeekRotationID DayOfWeek      TimeStart           TimeEnd
500     100            0 (=monday)    1900-01-01 08:00    1900-01-01 10:00

------------

One appointment every other monday for Q1 2021:

Periods

ID    DateStart   DateEnd    CustomerID
1     2021-1-1    2021-3-31  1

WeekRotations

ID    PeriodID    SequenceNr
100   1           1
101   1           2

Appointments

ID      WeekRotationID DayOfWeek      TimeStart           TimeEnd
500     100            0 (=monday)    1900-01-01 08:00    1900-01-01 10:00


------------

One appointment every 3 weeks on monday for Q1 2021:

Periods

ID    DateStart   DateEnd    CustomerID
1     2021-1-1    2021-3-31  1

WeekRotations

ID    PeriodID    SequenceNr
100   1           1
101   1           2
102   1           3

Appointments

ID      WeekRotationID DayOfWeek      TimeStart           TimeEnd
500     100            0 (=monday)    1900-01-01 08:00    1900-01-01 10:00
```

Comment: Hi, (1) Please provide DD+DML instead of description of your tables (including relations and indexes). (2) Please explain the relations between the table if the DDL does not include embedded relations.

Comment: And please show you attempt to date...

Comment: I've added more information, example data and what we have for the moment. Is this sufficiënt, or can I provide other details?

Comment: Presumably, you want to generate an appointment calendar for a specific range of dates when you run this query, don't you?  Can you post the code you've come up with? From the problem description you've outlined, I wouldn't expect it to be hugely complex and being able to see in more detail how you've tackled it may help us understand better the issues you're facing.

Comment: Also you mention 50,000+ customers. How many entries in the appointments table?

Comment: @RunCMD Can you explain what is the meaning of the column SequenceNr in the WeekRotation table? Moreover, an explanation the StartDate and EndDate in the Period tables, do you have any special requirement on it? (Only beginning and ending of a year ...)

Comment: In the query you have just provided, what does the function GetPrevMonday do? Why don't you use the DATEDIFF with the 'wk' in the date part parameter? If you feed the day '2021-03-01' (it is a Monday) to the function GetPrevMonday, what will it spit out? '2021-03-01' or '2021-02-22'?

Comment: @DVT SequenceNr: if you have a schedule that returns every three weeks, then you would have 3 WeekRotation objects, the first with SequenceNr 1, second with SequenceNr 2, third with SequenceNr 3. In theory you can have an infinte number of WeekRotations per Period. As for StartDate and EndDate, those can be any dates, so no requirement, only EndDate > StartDate.

Comment: @DVT: GetPrevMonday is a sql server function which returns the date of the monday previous to the date you give to it as a parameter. If you give it a monday, it will return that monday

Comment: @RunCMD If DayOfWeek=1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, should it be 5 for Friday?

Comment: @DVT, Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1, ...., Sunday = 6

Comment: @RunCMD Can you change the data in the question?

Comment: @DVT: oops sorry, edited.

Comment: Would you please share the code of GetPrevMonday?

Comment: Though weekrotationID 101 and 102 is not available in appointments table those will be considered since those have periodid same as periodid for workrotatonid 100. Right?

Comment: Does anybody ever change appointments? How do you deal with that with this setup?

Comment: @RunCMD - What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Modification on 14-Mar-2021 (Calendar dates stored in a table):**
**Query to store calendar dates in a table named Calendar:**

```
 ;WITH seq(n) AS 
 (
   SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
   WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, '1 jan 2021', '31 dec 2021')
 ),
 d(d) AS 
 (
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, '1 jan 2021') FROM seq
 ),
 calendar as(
 SELECT cast(d as date) Calendar_Date ,datepart(WK,D)  Week,DATEPART(WEEKDAY,D)-2 WeekDay,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by DATEPART(WEEKDAY,D) order by d)WekDaySequence FROM d 
 )
 select * into Calendar from Calendar
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**Query#1 (Taking time part from TimeStart and TimeEnd):**

```
 select  c.Calendar_date,WeekRotationID,periodid,AppointmentsID,dayofweek,timestart,timeend,maxSequenceNR,period_startdate ,period_enddate ,customerid,custome_rname from calendar c
 inner join (SELECT     wr.id WeekRotationID, wr.sequencenr,wr.periodid, a.id AppointmentsID, a.dayofweek ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), timestart, 108)timestart,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), timeend, 108)timeend,wr.maxSequenceNr,p.datestart period_startdate,p.dateend period_enddate,p.customerid,cust.name custome_rname
 FROM     
     (select id,periodid,sequencenr,max(sequencenr)over(partition by periodid)maxSequenceNR from WeekRotations) wr
    INNER JOIN Appointments a ON a.WeekRotationID = wr.ID  
    inner join periods p on wr.periodid=p.id 
    inner join customers cust on p.customerid=cust.id)t
    
    on c.WekDaySequence% t.maxSequenceNr=0  and t.dayofweek=c.WeekDay
    and c.calendar_date between t.period_startdate and period_enddate
 
 order by Calendar_Date
```

| Calendar_date | WeekRotationID | periodid | AppointmentsID | dayofweek | timestart | timeend | maxSequenceNR | period_startdate | period_enddate | customerid | custome_rname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-18 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00 | 10:00 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-02-08 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00 | 10:00 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-01 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00 | 10:00 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-22 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00 | 10:00 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |

**Query#2 (Taking time part from TimeStart and TimeEnd and concatenating with Date):**

```
 select  c.Calendar_date,WeekRotationID,periodid,AppointmentsID,dayofweek,concat(Calendar_Date ,' ',  timestart)timestart,concat(Calendar_Date ,' ',  timeend)timeend,maxSequenceNR,period_startdate ,period_enddate ,customerid,custome_rname from calendar c
 inner join (SELECT     wr.id WeekRotationID, wr.sequencenr,wr.periodid, a.id AppointmentsID, a.dayofweek ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), timestart, 108)timestart,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), timeend, 108)timeend,wr.maxSequenceNr,p.datestart period_startdate,p.dateend period_enddate,p.customerid,cust.name custome_rname
 FROM     
     (select id,periodid,sequencenr,max(sequencenr)over(partition by periodid)maxSequenceNR from WeekRotations) wr
    INNER JOIN Appointments a ON a.WeekRotationID = wr.ID  
    inner join periods p on wr.periodid=p.id 
    inner join customers cust on p.customerid=cust.id)t
    
    on c.WekDaySequence% t.maxSequenceNr=0  and t.dayofweek=c.WeekDay
    and c.calendar_date between t.period_startdate and period_enddate
 
 order by Calendar_Date
```

| Calendar_date | WeekRotationID | periodid | AppointmentsID | dayofweek | timestart | timeend | maxSequenceNR | period_startdate | period_enddate | customerid | custome_rname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-18 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 2021-01-18 08:00 | 2021-01-18 10:00 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-02-08 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 2021-02-08 08:00 | 2021-02-08 10:00 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-01 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 2021-03-01 08:00 | 2021-03-01 10:00 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-22 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 2021-03-22 08:00 | 2021-03-22 10:00 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=debac157dffa90401b154eb71845ab91)*

**I have taken only time part from appointment start and end time.

**One appointment each monday for Q1 2021:**

```
 ;WITH seq(n) AS 
 (
   SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
   WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, '1 jan 2021', '31 dec 2021')
 ),
 d(d) AS 
 (
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, '1 jan 2021') FROM seq
 ),
 calendar as(
 SELECT d Calendar_Date ,datepart(WK,D)  Week,DATEPART(WEEKDAY,D)-2 WeekDay,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by DATEPART(WEEKDAY,D) order by d)WekDaySequence FROM d 
 )
 
 select  c.Calendar_date,WeekRotationID,periodid,AppointmentsID,dayofweek,timestart,timeend,maxSequenceNR,period_startdate,period_enddate,customerid,custome_rname from calendar c
 inner join (SELECT     wr.id WeekRotationID, wr.sequencenr,wr.periodid, a.id AppointmentsID, a.dayofweek ,cast( a.timestart as time)timestart,cast(a.timeend as time)timeend,wr.maxSequenceNr,p.datestart period_startdate,p.dateend period_enddate,p.customerid,cust.name custome_rname
 FROM     
     (select id,periodid,sequencenr,max(sequencenr)over(partition by periodid)maxSequenceNR from WeekRotations) wr
    INNER JOIN Appointments a ON a.WeekRotationID = wr.ID  
    inner join periods p on wr.periodid=p.id 
    inner join customers cust on p.customerid=cust.id)t
    
    on c.WekDaySequence% t.maxSequenceNr=0  and t.dayofweek=c.WeekDay
    and c.calendar_date between t.period_startdate and period_enddate
 
 order by Calendar_Date
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

| Calendar_date | WeekRotationID | periodid | AppointmentsID | dayofweek | timestart | timeend | maxSequenceNR | period_startdate | period_enddate | customerid | custome_rname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-01-18 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-01-25 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-02-08 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-02-15 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-08 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-15 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-22 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-29 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |

**One appointment every other monday for Q1 2021:**

```
 ;WITH seq(n) AS 
 (
   SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
   WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, '1 jan 2021', '31 dec 2021')
 ),
 d(d) AS 
 (
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, '1 jan 2021') FROM seq
 ),
 calendar as(
 SELECT d Calendar_Date ,datepart(WK,D)  Week,DATEPART(WEEKDAY,D)-2 WeekDay,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by DATEPART(WEEKDAY,D) order by d)WekDaySequence FROM d 
 )
 
 select  c.Calendar_date,WeekRotationID,periodid,AppointmentsID,dayofweek,timestart,timeend,maxSequenceNR,period_startdate,period_enddate,customerid,custome_rname from calendar c
 inner join (SELECT     wr.id WeekRotationID, wr.sequencenr,wr.periodid, a.id AppointmentsID, a.dayofweek ,cast( a.timestart as time)timestart,cast(a.timeend as time)timeend,wr.maxSequenceNr,p.datestart period_startdate,p.dateend period_enddate,p.customerid,cust.name custome_rname
 FROM     
     (select id,periodid,sequencenr,max(sequencenr)over(partition by periodid)maxSequenceNR from WeekRotations) wr
    INNER JOIN Appointments a ON a.WeekRotationID = wr.ID  
    inner join periods p on wr.periodid=p.id 
    inner join customers cust on p.customerid=cust.id)t
    
    on c.WekDaySequence% t.maxSequenceNr=0  and t.dayofweek=c.WeekDay
    and c.calendar_date between t.period_startdate and period_enddate
 
 order by Calendar_Date
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

| Calendar_date | WeekRotationID | periodid | AppointmentsID | dayofweek | timestart | timeend | maxSequenceNR | period_startdate | period_enddate | customerid | custome_rname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-01-25 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-02-08 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-02-22 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-08 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-22 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |

**One appointment every 3 weeks on monday for Q1 2021:**

```
 ;WITH seq(n) AS 
 (
   SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM seq
   WHERE n < DATEDIFF(DAY, '1 jan 2021', '31 dec 2021')
 ),
 d(d) AS 
 (
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, '1 jan 2021') FROM seq
 ),
 calendar as(
 SELECT d Calendar_Date ,datepart(WK,D)  Week,DATEPART(WEEKDAY,D)-2 WeekDay,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by DATEPART(WEEKDAY,D) order by d)WekDaySequence FROM d 
 )
 
 select  c.Calendar_date,WeekRotationID,periodid,AppointmentsID,dayofweek,timestart,timeend,maxSequenceNR,period_startdate ,period_enddate ,customerid,custome_rname from calendar c
 inner join (SELECT     wr.id WeekRotationID, wr.sequencenr,wr.periodid, a.id AppointmentsID, a.dayofweek ,cast( a.timestart as time)timestart,cast(a.timeend as time)timeend,wr.maxSequenceNr,p.datestart period_startdate,p.dateend period_enddate,p.customerid,cust.name custome_rname
 FROM     
     (select id,periodid,sequencenr,max(sequencenr)over(partition by periodid)maxSequenceNR from WeekRotations) wr
    INNER JOIN Appointments a ON a.WeekRotationID = wr.ID  
    inner join periods p on wr.periodid=p.id 
    inner join customers cust on p.customerid=cust.id)t
    
    on c.WekDaySequence% t.maxSequenceNr=0  and t.dayofweek=c.WeekDay
    and c.calendar_date between t.period_startdate and period_enddate
 
 order by Calendar_Date
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

| Calendar_date | WeekRotationID | periodid | AppointmentsID | dayofweek | timestart | timeend | maxSequenceNR | period_startdate | period_enddate | customerid | custome_rname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-18 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-02-08 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |
| 2021-03-22 00:00:00.000 | 100 | 1 | 500 | 0 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 10:00:00.0000000 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 | 99 | Romel |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=355813862df55f26652132e1f0a0b0f1)*

Comment: Thanks for this answer! There are a few problems however: this returns dates outside of the period start and end dates, but that's easily fixed by adding ' where  Calendar_Date between period_startdate and period_enddate'
Another problem, is that for a 'three week' schedule, only every 4 week an appointment is returned. 
And a third problem is that if a period starts at 01/01/2020, and there is an appointment every three weeks on monday (seqNr 1), then the first appointment should be monday 20/01/2020, in your example the first date is sunday 19/01/2020? (please note that 0 = monday, and 6)

Comment: Ok let me get back to you soon.

Comment: @RunCMD I have incorporated date period and fixed the problem with sunday and monday misunderstanding (since monday=0). Please explain " Another problem, is that for a 'three week' schedule, only every 4 week an appointment is returned" a bit more with example.

Comment: Check my bottom last answer.

Comment: @RunCMD If a month starts at Tuesday then it's first Monday actually in week 2. Right?

Comment: And there are five Monday in March 2020. So for condition one appointment each Monday will the schedule be created for 5 Mondays? Or fifth week will be ignored?

Comment: If a month starts at Tuesday then it's first Monday actually in week 2: right.
And there are five Monday in March 2020. So for condition one appointment each Monday will the schedule be created for 5 Mondays? yes, every monday.

Comment: There's still a problem with the number of weeks though: in your example there is an appointment every three weeks, but in your result there are 4 weeks between 2020-01-20  and 2020-02-17...

Comment: Ok. I thought It's every third week of a month. but now i got you. it’s just every third week of all the weeks in date range. no problem at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229778/discussion-between-kazi-mohammad-ali-nur-and-run-cmd).

Comment: May I know reason behind downvoting this answer!

Answer (score 1):

From a series of questions (above and below), in the end, I asume this is the core question: Given your database structure and information, how to calculate the date appointment?

In my understand from reading the diagram, Period has the start and end date of a series of appointment.
WeekRotations give you the order of the week in the periods (SequenceNr). But note that this is cylcical (see discussion below). So if the cycle repeating every 3 weeks in a period of 50 weeks, you only get 3 records.
DayOfWeek gives you the day in that week. (0=Monday, 1=Tuesday,...)
For my SQL-Server collation, it is 1= Sunday, 2=Monday,..., 7=Saturday. If you use my query, please check your collation is consistent with it (for the purpose of system function).

Challenge 1: Get the Monday of the week of StartDate. (I do not use the user created function because they can cause problems with performance, depending on how they define. I prefer system function).

```
DATEADD( day, CASE DATEPART(weekday, Periods.DateStart) WHEN 1 THEN -6 ELSE 2 - DATEPART(weekday, Periods.DateStart)  END , Periods.DateStart )
```

Challenge 2: Get the metadata of rotation

```
SELECT
Periods.ID PeriodId
, MAX ( DATEDIFF (week, Periods.StartDate, Periods.EndDate ) + 1 ) NumberOfWeek
, COUNT(WeekRotations.ID) LengthOfCycle
FROM Periods
  INNER JOIN WeekRotations ON Periods.ID=WeekRotations.PeriodID
WHERE Periods.DateStart <= '2021-12-31' OR Periods.EndDate >= '2021-01-31'  -- cross year periods
GROUP BY Periods.ID = Periods.ID
) RotationMetadata
```

Challenge 3: Get the right appointment date

```
DATEADD ( day , Appointments.DayOfWeek, 
  DATEADD ( week, t.num * LengthOfCycle + WeekRotations.SequenceNr - 1, -- getting to the right week
              DATEADD( day, CASE DATEPART(weekday, Periods.DateStart) WHEN 1 THEN -6 ELSE 2 - DATEPART(weekday, Periods.DateStart)  END , Periods.DateStart )
  )
) AppointmentDate
```

So, the final query is below. It would be helpful if you have a TallyTable in your database

```
;WITH d AS (
SELECT digits
FROM ( VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9) ) d(Digits)
), TallyTable AS (
SELECT d1.digits *10 + d2.digits num
FROM d d1
  CROSS JOIN d d2
WHERE d1.digits *10 + d2.digits < 60  -- get a large enough number to satisfy all use case. 
)
SELECT   tbl.*, Customers.*
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    DATEADD ( day , Appointments.DayOfWeek, 
      DATEADD ( week, t.num * LengthOfCycle + WeekRotations.SequenceNr - 1,
                  DATEADD( day, CASE DATEPART(weekday, Periods.DateStart) WHEN 1 THEN -6 ELSE 2 - DATEPART(weekday, Periods.DateStart)  END , Periods.DateStart )
      )
    ) AppointmentDate
    , Periods.DateStart, Periods.DateEnd, Periods.Id PeriodId, Periods.CustomerId
    , WeekRotations.Id WeekRotationID, WeekRotations.SequenceNr
    , Appointments.DayOfWeek, Appointments.TimeStart, Appointments.TimeEnd
FROM 
    Periods                      
    INNER JOIN WeekRotations ON Periods.ID                  = WeekRotations.PeriodID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Appointments  ON Appointments.WeekRotationID = WeekRotations.ID  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
        p.ID PeriodId
        , MAX ( DATEDIFF (week, p.DateStart, p.DateEnd ) + 1 ) NumberOfWeek
        , COUNT(WeekRotations.ID) LengthOfCycle
        FROM Periods p
          INNER JOIN WeekRotations ON p.ID=WeekRotations.PeriodID
        WHERE p.DateStart <= '2021-12-31' OR p.DateEnd >= '2021-01-01'  -- cross year periods
        GROUP BY p.ID 
        ) RotationMetadata
        ON RotationMetadata.PeriodId = Periods.ID
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT num FROM TallyTable WHERE num <= (RotationMetadata.NumberOfWeek / RotationMetadata.LengthOfCycle + 1 )
    ) t
WHERE
    Periods.DateStart <= '2021-12-31' OR Periods.DateEnd >= '2021-01-01' -- cross year periods
) tbl
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers ON tbl.CustomerId = Customers.Id
WHERE tbl.AppointmentDate BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31' 
AND tbl.AppointmentDate BETWEEN tbl.DateStart AND tbl.DateEnd
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! This seems to be going in the right direction, but I think it's missing an important point: suppose i have 1 'periods' record, with start = '2021-1-1' and end '2021-12-31', with 1 weekrotation, and 1 appointment on monday, the query shoud return all mondays in 2021. I think now it's just returning the first monday?

Comment: Should that one be taken care of by your SequenceNr, with each week has one SequenceNr?

Comment: SequenceNr just indicates the order of that week in the rotation. So for example, if you have a customer which has an appointment every other week, there will be 2 weekrotation records, width SequenceNr 1 and 2, and where weekrotation 1 will have 1 appointment, and weekrotation 2 will be empty. I hope it's clear this way?

Comment: Can you give examples in your question of how your WeekRotation would look like in cases you have appointment once a week, once every 2 weeks, once every 3 weeks?

Comment: added examples in question

Comment: @RunCMD I modified the answer with the new information you gave.

Comment: @RunCMD Please check my answer. I have tried to generate all three situation. I didn't join customer table but that's easily be joined. Hope It will solved your problem.

Comment: @DVT wow, looks nice, thanks. However, I'm getting 2 synax errors: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Comment: @RunCMD Can you try again?

Comment: @DVT sorry I'm getting: 
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'CROSS'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Comment: @RunCMD One more.

Comment: When I change StartDate to DateStart, and EndDate to DateEnd, as also stated in other places in the query, and because the actual db fields have these names, i get :Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
Invalid column name 'DateStart'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
Invalid column name 'DateEnd'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 42
The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'tbl'.

Comment: @RunCMD I converted all of these StartDate to DateStart and EndDate to DateEnd

Comment: still the same error: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
Invalid column name 'DateStart'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
Invalid column name 'DateEnd'.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 42
The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'tbl'.

Comment: @RunCMD I removed the Customers table to reduce the change of duplicate column in subquery.

Comment: @RunCMD I updated the query to make sure it only pick up the appointments with date between StartDate and EndDate

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a dedicated table to store all the date of the years you planing to cover, Lets say from 2020-01-01 to 2050-12-31. The column structure of this tables is simple:

```
create table dbo.DateTable ([Date] date primary key, DayOfWeek tinyint, WeekNumber int)
```

Where the WeekNumber whould be the number of week between the tables first entry, and the current entry. Can easily be obtained by `update dt set WeekNumber = datediff(week, @vFirstDate, dt.Date) from dbo.DateTable dt`, where the @vFirstDate is the min of Date from the table.

To get the actual dates for a Period, you only need to join the DateTabe 2 times:

- First on the `Period.DateStart = Date condition`, let's call it fdt
- Then on the `Date between Period.DateStart and Period.DateEnd`, let's call id dt

If the WeekNumber difference is dividable by the SequenceNr from WeekRotation you got the correct Date.

To further narrow the DateTable down, you can join the Appointments table too on the condition of `dt.DayOfWeek = Appointments.DayOfWeek`

The DateTable only need's to be populated once, and extended once a year, to increase it with the next year.

Comment: This isn't possible as there are +50.000 customers and their scheduled appointments for the future, both near and far, change constantly....

Answer (score 0):

Try this using a tally table. Retrieving only the right number of records from the tally table and calculating all the dates for all the weeks in between start and end dates. Determine what week cycle it is and then join to the weekrotation table for the right week.

```
;with Tally (n) AS
(
    -- 100 rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
),
weeks as
(
    select TOP (select top 1 datepart(wk, dateend) - DATEPART(wk, datestart) from periods)
        periods.id as periodid,
        dateadd(wk, n - 1, datestart) curDate, n as wk, 
        (select max(sequencenr) from weekrotations wr2 where wr2.periodid = periods.id) as mxSequence
    from Tally
    CROSS JOIN Periods
)
select a.id, a.weekrotationid, a.dayofweek, timestart, timeend
from weeks w
inner join weekrotations wr
    on wr.periodid = w.periodid and wr.sequencenr = wk % mxSequence
inner join appointments a 
    on a.weekrotationid = wr.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are seeking. Can accomplish your desired results by using Variable Tables, Recursive CTEs, and some basic built in functions such as DATEADD, DATEPART, DATENAME, DATEDIFF and MAX. Other than that, there is some math involved for creating a 10 year calendar that can be used for to determine the appointment dates.

```
--DECLARATION OF VARIABLE TABLE
DECLARE @Calendar TABLE (
                            [DWDateKey] DATE
                            ,[DayDate] INT
                            ,[DayOfWeekName] VARCHAR(10)
                            ,[DayOfWeekID] INT
                            ,[WeekNumber] INT
                            ,[Year] INT
                            ,[QuarterNumber] INT
                        );

--DECLARATION OF VARIABLE TABLE
DECLARE @Reccurence TABLE (
                            [PeriodID] INT
                            ,[ReccurenceByWeek] INT
                            );

--GET MAX SEQUENCE NUMBER BY PERIOD ID
INSERT INTO @Reccurence
SELECT PeriodID
      ,MAX(SequenceNr)
FROM WeekRotations AS WR
GROUP BY PeriodID;

--RECURSIVE COMMON TABLE EXPRESION (CTE) TO POPULATE A 10 YEAR CALENDAR
WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, SYSDATETIME()), 0) AS DATE) AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM CTE_DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= CAST(DATEADD(YY,10,DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, SYSDATETIME()) +1, 0))) AS DATE)
)
INSERT INTO @Calendar
SELECT [DWDateKey] = [date]
          ,[DayDate] = DATEPART(dd,[date])
          ,[DayOfWeekName] = DATENAME(dw,[date])
          ,[DayOfWeekID] = ((DATEPART(dw,[date]) + 5) % 7 + 1) - 1
          ,[WeekNumber] = DATEPART(WEEK, [date])         
          ,[Year] = DATEPART(YY,[date])      
          ,[QuarterNumber] = DATEPART(QUARTER, [date])
FROM CTE_DatesTable AS CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);  


--RECURSIVE COMMON TABLE EXPRESION (CTE) TO POPULATE LISTING OF APPPINTMENT DATES
;WITH 
CTE_FinalResult 
AS
(
SELECT SubQry.CustomerFirstName
       ,SubQry.CustomerLastName
       ,SubQry.AppointmentDate
       ,SubQry.AppointmentStartTime
       ,SubQry.AppointmentEndTime
       ,SubQry.AppointmentID
       ,SubQry.WeekRotationID
       ,SubQry.PeriodID
       ,SubQry.DateEnd
FROM 
    (
    SELECT Customer.FirstName AS CustomerFirstName
            , Customer.LastName  AS CustomerLastName
            , Calendar.DWDateKey AS AppointmentDate
            , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(Appointments.TimeStart AS TIME), 100) AS AppointmentStartTime
            , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(Appointments.TimeEnd AS TIME), 100) AS AppointmentEndTime
            , Appointments.ID AS AppointmentID
            , WeekRotations.ID AS WeekRotationID
            , Period.ID AS PeriodID  
            , Period.DateEnd 
            , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer.CustomerID ORDER BY Calendar.DWDateKey) AS RNK
    FROM @Calendar AS Calendar
    JOIN Period
        ON Calendar.DWDateKey BETWEEN Period.DateStart AND Period.DateEnd
    JOIN Customer
        ON Period.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
    JOIN WeekRotation
        ON Period.ID = WeekRotations.PeriodID
    JOIN Appointments AS Appointments
        ON WeekRotations.ID = Appointments.WeekRotationID
        AND Appointments.[DayOfWeek] = Calendar.[DayOfWeekID]
    ) SubQry
WHERE SubQry.RNK = 1

UNION ALL 

SELECT CTE_FinalResult.CustomerFirstName
        , CTE_FinalResult.CustomerLastName
        , DATEADD(WEEK, R.ReccurenceByWeek, CTE_FinalResult.AppointmentDate) AS AppointmentDate
        , CTE_FinalResult.AppointmentStartTime
        , CTE_FinalResult.AppointmentEndTime
        , CTE_FinalResult.AppointmentID
        , CTE_FinalResult.WeekRotationID
        , CTE_FinalResult.PeriodID
        , CTE_FinalResult.DateEnd
FROM CTE_FinalResult
JOIN @Reccurence AS R
    ON CTE_FinalResult.PeriodID = R.PeriodID 
WHERE DATEADD(WEEK, R.ReccurenceByWeek, CTE_FinalResult.AppointmentDate) <= CTE_FinalResult.DateEnd
)

--FINAL SELECT STATEMENT
SELECT FinalResult.CustomerFirstName
        ,FinalResult.CustomerLastName
        ,FinalResult.AppointmentDate
        ,FinalResult.AppointmentStartTime
        ,FinalResult.AppointmentEndTime
        ,FinalResult.AppointmentID
        ,FinalResult.WeekRotationID
        ,FinalResult.PeriodID
FROM CTE_FinalResult AS FinalResult
ORDER BY PeriodID 
         ,AppointmentDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Here is the code with some example data that can be ran for testing by using variable tables to store test data.

```
--EXAMPLE DATA FOR TESTING PURPOSES

DECLARE @Period TABLE (ID INT, DateStart DATE, DateEnd DATE, CustomerID INT)
DECLARE @WeekRotation TABLE (ID INT, PeriodID INT, SequenceNr INT)
DECLARE @Appointment TABLE (ID INT, WeekRotationID INT, [DayOfWeek] INT, TimeStart SMALLDATETIME, TimeEnd SMALLDATETIME)
DECLARE @Customer TABLE (CustomerID INT, FirstName VARCHAR(100), LastName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Period
VALUES (1,'2021-01-01','2021-03-31',1)
,(2,'2021-01-01','2021-03-31',2)
,(3,'2021-01-01','2021-03-31',3)

INSERT INTO @WeekRotation
VALUES (100,1,1)
,(101,2,1)
,(102,2,2)
,(103,3,1)
,(104,3,2)
,(105,3,3)

INSERT INTO @Appointment
VALUES (500,100,0,'1900-01-01 08:00','1900-01-01 10:00')
,(500,101,2,'1900-01-01 09:00','1900-01-01 11:00')
,(500,103,5,'1900-01-01 10:00','1900-01-01 13:00')

INSERT INTO @Customer
VALUES (1,'John','Doe')
,(2,'Jane','Smith')
,(3,'Jake','Weston')

---------------------------------------------

--DECLARATION OF VARIABLE TABLE
DECLARE @Calendar TABLE (
                            [DWDateKey] DATE
                            ,[DayDate] INT
                            ,[DayOfWeekName] VARCHAR(10)
                            ,[DayOfWeekID] INT
                            ,[WeekNumber] INT
                            ,[Year] INT
                            ,[QuarterNumber] INT
                        );

--DECLARATION OF VARIABLE TABLE
DECLARE @Reccurence TABLE (
                            [PeriodID] INT
                            ,[ReccurenceByWeek] INT
                            );

--GET MAX SEQUENCE NUMBER BY PERIOD ID
INSERT INTO @Reccurence
SELECT PeriodID
      ,MAX(SequenceNr)
FROM @WeekRotation AS WR
GROUP BY PeriodID;

--RECURSIVE COMMON TABLE EXPRESION (CTE) TO POPULATE A 10 YEAR CALENDAR
WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, SYSDATETIME()), 0) AS DATE) AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM CTE_DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= CAST(DATEADD(YY,10,DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, SYSDATETIME()) +1, 0))) AS DATE)
)
INSERT INTO @Calendar
SELECT [DWDateKey] = [date]
          ,[DayDate] = DATEPART(dd,[date])
          ,[DayOfWeekName] = DATENAME(dw,[date])
          ,[DayOfWeekID] = ((DATEPART(dw,[date]) + 5) % 7 + 1) - 1
          ,[WeekNumber] = DATEPART(WEEK, [date])         
          ,[Year] = DATEPART(YY,[date])      
          ,[QuarterNumber] = DATEPART(QUARTER, [date])
FROM CTE_DatesTable AS CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);  


--RECURSIVE COMMON TABLE EXPRESION (CTE) TO POPULATE LISTING OF APPPINTMENT DATES
;WITH 
CTE_FinalResult 
AS
(
SELECT SubQry.CustomerFirstName
       ,SubQry.CustomerLastName
       ,SubQry.AppointmentDate
       ,SubQry.AppointmentStartTime
       ,SubQry.AppointmentEndTime
       ,SubQry.AppointmentID
       ,SubQry.WeekRotationID
       ,SubQry.PeriodID
       ,SubQry.DateEnd
FROM 
    (
    SELECT Customer.FirstName AS CustomerFirstName
            , Customer.LastName  AS CustomerLastName
            , Calendar.DWDateKey AS AppointmentDate
            , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(Appointments.TimeStart AS TIME), 100) AS AppointmentStartTime
            , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(Appointments.TimeEnd AS TIME), 100) AS AppointmentEndTime
            , Appointments.ID AS AppointmentID
            , WeekRotations.ID AS WeekRotationID
            , Period.ID AS PeriodID  
            , Period.DateEnd 
            , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer.CustomerID ORDER BY Calendar.DWDateKey) AS RNK
    FROM @Calendar AS Calendar
    JOIN @Period AS Period
        ON Calendar.DWDateKey BETWEEN Period.DateStart AND Period.DateEnd
    JOIN @Customer AS Customer
        ON Period.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
    JOIN @WeekRotation AS WeekRotations
        ON Period.ID = WeekRotations.PeriodID
    JOIN @Appointment AS Appointments
        ON WeekRotations.ID = Appointments.WeekRotationID
        AND Appointments.[DayOfWeek] = Calendar.[DayOfWeekID]
    ) SubQry
WHERE SubQry.RNK = 1

UNION ALL 

SELECT CTE_FinalResult.CustomerFirstName
        , CTE_FinalResult.CustomerLastName
        , DATEADD(WEEK, R.ReccurenceByWeek, CTE_FinalResult.AppointmentDate) AS AppointmentDate
        , CTE_FinalResult.AppointmentStartTime
        , CTE_FinalResult.AppointmentEndTime
        , CTE_FinalResult.AppointmentID
        , CTE_FinalResult.WeekRotationID
        , CTE_FinalResult.PeriodID
        , CTE_FinalResult.DateEnd
FROM CTE_FinalResult
JOIN @Reccurence AS R
    ON CTE_FinalResult.PeriodID = R.PeriodID 
WHERE DATEADD(WEEK, R.ReccurenceByWeek, CTE_FinalResult.AppointmentDate) <= CTE_FinalResult.DateEnd
)

--FINAL SELECT STATEMENT
SELECT FinalResult.CustomerFirstName
        ,FinalResult.CustomerLastName
        ,FinalResult.AppointmentDate
        ,FinalResult.AppointmentStartTime
        ,FinalResult.AppointmentEndTime
        ,FinalResult.AppointmentID
        ,FinalResult.WeekRotationID
        ,FinalResult.PeriodID
FROM CTE_FinalResult AS FinalResult
ORDER BY PeriodID 
         ,AppointmentDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**Results From Test Data and Code with Variable Tables**

| CustomerFirstName | CustomerLastName | AppointmentDate | AppointmentStartTime | AppointmentEndTime | AppointmentID | WeekRotationID | PeriodID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | 2021-01-04 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-01-11 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-01-18 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-01-25 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-02-01 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-02-08 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-02-15 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-02-22 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-03-01 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-03-08 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-03-15 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-03-22 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| John | Doe | 2021-03-29 | 8:00AM | 10:00AM | 500 | 100 | 1 |
| Jane | Smith | 2021-01-06 | 9:00AM | 11:00AM | 500 | 101 | 2 |
| Jane | Smith | 2021-01-20 | 9:00AM | 11:00AM | 500 | 101 | 2 |
| Jane | Smith | 2021-02-03 | 9:00AM | 11:00AM | 500 | 101 | 2 |
| Jane | Smith | 2021-02-17 | 9:00AM | 11:00AM | 500 | 101 | 2 |
| Jane | Smith | 2021-03-03 | 9:00AM | 11:00AM | 500 | 101 | 2 |
| Jane | Smith | 2021-03-17 | 9:00AM | 11:00AM | 500 | 101 | 2 |
| Jane | Smith | 2021-03-31 | 9:00AM | 11:00AM | 500 | 101 | 2 |
| Jake | Weston | 2021-01-02 | 10:00AM | 1:00PM | 500 | 103 | 3 |
| Jake | Weston | 2021-01-23 | 10:00AM | 1:00PM | 500 | 103 | 3 |
| Jake | Weston | 2021-02-13 | 10:00AM | 1:00PM | 500 | 103 | 3 |
| Jake | Weston | 2021-03-06 | 10:00AM | 1:00PM | 500 | 103 | 3 |
| Jake | Weston | 2021-03-27 | 10:00AM | 1:00PM | 500 | 103 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to unfold all the days in the period, then calculate the week day and the week No relative to the period start date for each date, then we can easily identify the date with scheduled appointments by checking week No and week day against week rotation and appointments settings.

Here is the query with your third example data -

```
with Period as (
select *
  from (VALUES (1,'2021-01-01','2021-03-31',1)
       ) p(ID, DateStart, DateEnd, CustomerID) 
)
,WeekRotation as (
select *
  from (VALUES (100,1,1)
              ,(101,1,2)
              ,(102,1,3)
       ) w(ID, PeriodID, SequenceNr)
)
,Appointment as (
select a.ID
      ,a.WeekRotationID
      ,case when DayOfWeek + 2 <= 7 then DayOfWeek + 2 else 1 end DayOfWeek -- align DateOfWeek with DatePart(weekday, date) 
      ,a.TimeStart
      ,a.TimeEnd
  from (VALUES (500,100,0,'1900-01-01 08:00','1900-01-01 10:00')
       ) a(ID, WeekRotationID, DayOfWeek, TimeStart, TimeEnd)
)
,schedule as (
   select p.ID            PeriodID
         ,w.SequenceNr    WeekNo
         ,a.DayOfWeek
         ,a.TimeStart
         ,a.TimeEnd
     from Period p 
     join WeekRotation w on p.ID = w.PeriodID
left join Appointment  a on w.ID = a.WeekRotationID
)
,UnfoldDate as (
select p.ID        PeriodID
      ,p.DateStart PeriodStartDate
      ,DateAdd(day, seq.number - 1, p.DateStart) date
  from Period p
      ,(select distinct number FROM master..[spt_values] where number BETWEEN 1 AND 1000) seq -- a quick way to get sequence numbers, replace it with your own tally table on production. Also assume the period length is less than 1000 days
 where seq.number <=  DateDiff(day, p.DateStart, p.DateEnd) + 1
)
,RotationCount as (
select PeriodID
      ,count(0) Cnt
  from WeekRotation
 group
    by PeriodID
)
,DateTable as (
select ud.PeriodID
      ,ud.date
      ,datediff(week, ud.PeriodStartDate, ud.date) % rc.cnt + 1 WeekNo
      ,datepart(weekday, date) DayOfWeek
  from UnfoldDate    ud
      ,RotationCount rc
 where ud.PeriodID = rc.PeriodID
)
select d.periodID
      ,d.date
      ,s.TimeStart
      ,s.TimeEnd
  from schedule  s
      ,DateTable d
 where s.PeriodID = d.PeriodID
   and s.WeekNo = d.WeekNo
   and s.DayOfWeek = d.DayOfWeek
 order
    by d.periodID
      ,d.date
      ,s.TimeStart
```

The output is -

```
1   2021-01-18 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 08:00    1900-01-01 10:00
1   2021-02-08 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 08:00    1900-01-01 10:00
1   2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 08:00    1900-01-01 10:00
1   2021-03-22 00:00:00.000 1900-01-01 08:00    1900-01-01 10:00
```